# Not visible overlay picture over a SurfaceView

Tags: android, overlay, surfaceview

I'm trying to write a vintage videogame for Android devices, which "screen" is displayed through a `SurfaceView` subclass called `GraphicSurface`. I would also show on the bottom-right corner of the layout an alpha overlay of a "joypad" picture (`ImageView` subclass called `JoyPadView`) touch-events sensitive, to use as game controller. Reading around I chose the most accredited solution as follows but it doesn't work. In fact the joypad never appears although it still receive touch events.
I guess the problem is the surfaceView drawing thread continuing to cover the joypad picture but I don't know what really happens and how to manage it.

Here is the layout XML code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.example.munchman.GraphicSurface
    android:id="@+id/graphicSurface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.example.munchman.JoyPadView
    android:id="@+id/joyPadView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:src="@drawable/joypad"
    android:visibility="visible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

And here's the (simplified) code of `SurfaceView` subclass:

```
public class GraphicSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

//... class attributes  

// INNER CLASS: DRAWING THREAD --------------
class DrawingThread extends Thread {
    private boolean running = false;

    public synchronized void setRunning(boolean run) {
        running = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long timeInterval = 1000l / fps;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long sleepTime;
        Bitmap scrBmp;
        Canvas c;

        while (running) {
            // DRAWING
            c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = holder.lockCanvas();
                if (c != null && screen != null) {
                    synchronized (holder) {  
                        //... "screen" drawing code  
                        c.drawBitmap(scrBmp, origRect, destRect, null);
                    }               
                }
                else {
                    if (c == null) Log.w(TAG, "run(): lockCanvas returned null canvas");
                    else Log.w(TAG, "run(): null screen!");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "run(): drawing canvas:" + Log.getStackTraceString(e) );
            } finally {
                if (c != null) holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
            // SLEEP TIME
            sleepTime = timeInterval - (System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0) sleep(sleepTime);
                else sleep(timeInterval);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "run(): sleeping: " + e);
            }               
        }
    }
}

private DrawingThread drawingThread = null;

// CONSTRUCTORS -------------------
public GraphicSurface(Context context) {    
    super(context);
    init();
}

public GraphicSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
    super(context, attributes);
    init();
}

public GraphicSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attributes, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attributes, defStyle);
    init();
}

// CLASS METHODS -----------------
private void init () {
Log.d(TAG, "init()");
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
drawingThread.setName(TAG);
fps = DEFAULT_FPS;
//... other code  
}

  /** Enable the SurfaceView embedded drawing thread.
     */
    public synchronized void startDrawingThread() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startDrawingThread()");
        if (drawingThread == null) drawingThread = new DrawingThread();
        if (!drawingThread.isAlive()) {
            drawingThread.setRunning(true);
            drawingThread.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The SurfaceView's surface should always be below everything, and the "view" part of the SurfaceView is transparent.  Are you calling http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean) or setting an opaque background for the SurfaceView?

Comment: **Problem solved!** Thank you very much for the tip! In fact I called `setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)` in `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated()` method, unaware that it would hide the surface image! It was enough to remove the call to solve the problem! Anyway, again I think Android documentation isn't comprehensive enough especially for the unexperienced.